# Cassandra 1.2 removing an item from a list column and removing the row when the list is empty

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra 1.2 Column Family which looks like this:

```
food: 'steak'
value: 10
desserts: ['chocolate cake','banana pie','strawberry icecream']
```

And I need to delete one the desserts from this row , for instance 'chocolate cake' but if the list of desserts result in an empty list after removing one of the items I need to delete the entire row, is there a way to achieve this in a single query in Cassandra? If not, what's the best way to do it?

More info: the query I'm using to remove one of the items in the list is this:

```
update Table
set desserts = desserts - ['chocolate cake']
where food = 'steak'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort advanced functionality on Collection framework is yet to be supported in cassandra. Right now i guess you have to perform two queries to complete the operation.

Answer (score 2):

One line statement to delete an element from a list:

```
DELETE desserts[1] FROM table WHERE where food = 'steak';
```

For reference,
Point 6 in the below link from datastax:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_list_t.html

This link discusses in detail about list type uses in cassandra.